# JavaScript runtime error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Invalid JSON primitive?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, json, telerik

Below is my RadSlider:

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" CssClass="table-content headerGrid" Width="500px"
        BorderColor="Black" Visible="false">
        <telerik:RadGrid ID="rdGrddepencies" runat="server" Visible="false" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
            BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" Width="500px" OnItemDataBound="rdGrddepencies_Itemdatabound">
            <MasterTableView AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                <Columns>
                    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <%--<asp:Label ID="lblId" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("taskId") %>'></asp:Label>--%>
                            <asp:Label ID="lbltaskid" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <div id="DivSlider1" runat="server">
                                <telerik:RadSlider ID="RadSlider2" Value="100"  runat="server" MinimumValue="0" MaximumValue="100"
                                    ItemType="Tick" SmallChange="10" LargeChange="100" Height="48px" Width="80px"
                                    AnimationDuration="100" TrackPosition="BottomRight" OnValueChanged="RadSlider1_ValueChanged"
                                    AutoPostBack="true" OnClientValueChanging="demo.sliderClientValueChanging" OnClientSlideStart="demo.sliderClientSlideStart"
                                    OnClientSlideEnd="demo.sliderClientSlideEnd" ShowDecreaseHandle="false" ShowIncreaseHandle="false"
                                    ClientIDMode="Static">
                                </telerik:RadSlider>
                            </div>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" Text="Delete" runat="server" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                </Columns>
            </MasterTableView>
            <ClientSettings>
                <ClientEvents OnRowClick="RowClick" />
            </ClientSettings>
        </telerik:RadGrid>
    </asp:Panel>
```

In my application i am using `telerik:RadSlider`. I tried to add multiple `telerik:RadSlider` while click add button. If it's only one `telerik:RadSlider` in the page ondroggable event fired perfectly. But i tried click and add multiple `telerik:RadSlider` and ondrog second `telerik:RadSlider`.
I am getting below error :

```
JavaScript runtime error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Invalid JSON primitive.
```

How to solve this issue.

Any idea ?

Comment: Sounds like you have an Invalid JSON primitive... Perhaps show the JSON and fix it?

Comment: In my page i never used any json formated code. How can i identify that ?

Comment: please help me to fix.

Comment: Look in the console on the network tab to see what is sent. For example set_dataSource is using JSON

Comment: Remove ClientIDMode=Static. Grids repeat the controls on each row so you will end up with many controls with the same ID. Also, this mode is not supported by the Telerik AJAX controls.